# How to override jQuery drop-down UI styles?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

I would like to seek technical help regarding a jquery accordion implementation.

I have this existing page
[image: Screenshot_0]

and I've implemented jQuery Accordion UI in the page which is now like this
[image: Screenshot_1]

However, I'm experiencing a problem of overriding UI styles. As you can notice on the second image attachment the `Filter by Category` dropdown is no longer displaying. How can I override this UI styles on this?

This is the existing code (before I implement jQuery)

```
<div class="fields">
    <div class="ui-select">
        <div id="category-button" 
             class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
            <span>Filter by Category</span>
            <select onchange="document.techforms.submit();" id="category" name="category">
                <option value="">Filter by Category</option>
                <option value="4">Administration</option>
                <option value="5">Audits and Reports</option>
                <option value="6">Commissioning</option>
                <option value="7">Documentation</option>
                <option value="8">ETTiS</option>
                <option value="9">Materials</option>
                <option value="11">Permit and Requests</option>
                <option value="12">Permits and Requests</option>
                <option value="13">Project Management</option>
                <option value="14">Project Specific Forms</option>
                <option value="15">OHS FORMS</option>
                <option value="61">Test Sheets &amp; Commissioning Document Templates</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

now, this is the code after i implemented the jquery ui library

```
<div class="fields">
    <select name="category" id="category" onchange="document.techforms.submit();" style="display: none;">
        <option value="">Filter by Category</option>
        <option value="4">Administration</option>
        <option value="5">Audits and Reports</option>
        <option value="6">Commissioning</option>
        <option value="7">Documentation</option>
        <option value="8">ETTiS</option>
        <option value="9">Materials</option>
        <option value="11">Permit and Requests</option>
        <option value="12">Permits and Requests</option>
        <option value="13">Project Management</option>
        <option value="14">Project Specific Forms</option>
        <option value="15">OHS FORMS</option>
        <option value="61">Test Sheets &amp; Commissioning Document Templates</option>
    </select>
    <span class="ui-selectmenu-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" id="category-button" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="category-menu" aria-haspopup="true" style="width: 0px;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span class="ui-selectmenu-text">Filter by Category</span></span>
</div>
```

Is there any possible way to resolve this? I want to retain the existing design of the `Filter by Category` dropdownlist.

Comment: @DavidDomain what do you mean sir?

Comment: did you notice this `style="display: none;"` ? You are actually not displying that dropdown in your after jQuery implementation code snippet

Comment: @Babel yep..i saw that but that already, even if i deleted that style. it will show a plain dropdownlist with no style..on which i wanted to happen is to retain the original dropdownlist style

Comment: @nhoyti Okay when you tried like that are you missing style of it ? can you  post a screen or something

Answer (score 0):

Okay !!

I think you are missing these in your altered code snippet.

```
<div class="ui-select">
    <div id="category-button" 
         class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
```

Add above line to `div` instead of `<span>`